# No entiendo porque al realizar la resta de 0.15 - 0.10 me da 0.499999, utilizando variables tipo float, (C++)

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuY3l.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN2uJ.png`introducir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN2uJ.png%60introducir) el código aquí`

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, por favor, no pongas imágenes, pon código. Que las imágenes y los enlaces no sean imprescindibles para entender la pregunta y poder darte respuestas

Comment: Esto que ocurre es normal, es culpa del método que usan para guardar números con decimales (IEEE 754), te lo encontrarás en cualquier lenguaje.
Piensa cuantos decimales quieres, y redondea.

Comment: Gracias Arnau!!